# Is there a way to speed up a DISTINCT query?

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-10, distinct, query-performance

I have a table t in a database (PostgreSQL 10.4):

```
\d t;
                Table "public.t"
  Column  |          Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default 
----------+------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 sn       | character varying(11)  |           |          | 
 site     | character varying(50)  |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "site_2018_idx" btree (site), tablespace "indexspace"
    "sn_2018_idx" btree (sn), tablespace "indexspace"
```

I need to find distinct 'sn's for specific site, and I do it like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sn FROM t WHERE site='a_b301_1' ORDER BY sn ;
```

It works, but is very slow, to return 75 distinct 'sn' values it takes about 8 minutes!
Is there a way to speed it up?
The explain analyze gives this output:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=42873094.21..42873103.25 rows=3615 width=12) (actual time=190431.413..190431.417 rows=75 loops=1)
   Output: sn
   Sort Key: t.sn
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 28kB
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=42872844.42..42872880.57 rows=3615 width=12) (actual time=190431.233..190431.263 rows=75 loops=1)
         Output: sn
         Group Key: t.sn
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.t  (cost=874850.36..42695793.24 rows=70820471 width=12) (actual time=8755.163..168773.143 rows=43096912 loops=1)
               Output: sn, site
               Recheck Cond: ((t.site)::text = 'a_b301_1'::text)
               Heap Blocks: exact=783666
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on site_2018_idx  (cost=0.00..857145.24 rows=70820471 width=0) (actual time=8540.835..8540.835 rows=43096912 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((t.site)::text = 'a_b301_1'::text)
 Planning time: 0.466 ms
 Execution time: 190433.289 ms
(15 rows)
```

**Additional information**

After I created another index, as was recommended `(site, sn)`, the time decreased significantly, from 8 min to 30 sec. It is great, I just don't understand why is this the case? How is one multi-column index better than two separate indexes, in this case?

Comment: try to add an index with both fields this order; `(site, sn)` and try again. The thing is if the value for site='a_b301_1' is somehow mostly used in your queries, then you can use either partial index or partitioning.

Comment: After I created another index, as was recommended, the time decreased significantly, from 8 min to 30 sec. It is great, I just don't understand why is this the case? How is one multicolumn index is better than two separate indexes, in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As suggested, an index on `(site, sn)` could speed this up, especially if the table is well-vacuumed so that it benefits from index-only scans.

If that is not enough of a speed up, then there is a way to use this index in a "skip scan" or [*"Loose Index Scan"*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63293/what-is-a-loose-index-scan) to speed up queries where the number of distinct values is much lower than the size of the index. Unfortunately PostgreSQL's planner does not automatically detect opportunities for this, but you can force it yourself by writing a recursive common table expression.  You can find a discussion of this technique on the [PostgreSQL wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan), although you will need to adapt it to your parameterized version.

The resulting queries are quite ugly, so you might want to wrap them into a view.  Or in this case, since it is parameterized, into a set-returning function.  Something like this works for me:

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.foobar(text) RETURNS SETOF text
    LANGUAGE sql
    AS $_$ with recursive r as (
  (select sn from t where site = $1 order by sn limit 1)
   union all
  SELECT (SELECT t.sn FROM t WHERE site=$1 and t.sn > r.sn ORDER BY sn LIMIT 1) from r where sn is not null
)
select * from r where r.sn is not null $_$;
```

Setting up the table and index with:

```
create table t as select 
    floor(random()*1.2)::int::varchar as site, 
    (-floor(50*log(random()))::int)::varchar as sn 
from generate_series(1,10000000);

create index on t (site ,sn);
```

Comment: Thank you jjanes, i'm trying to use your function, and got this: "ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 4:   (select sn from t where site = $1 order...
                                                          ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts." My columns are "character varying" type, so should I use 'text' instead of 'integer' in the function?

Comment: Well, I changed 'integer' to 'text' and used the function (I called it 'getsn'), but the result is not correct: instead of 75 lines I got just one: getsn  ------------- 716K000098 (1 row).

Comment: I changed the types in my example to varchar and added the test case to create the table and index I used.  It still works for me as the text type, I don't why it wouldn't work for you.

Comment: Thank you jjanes, your modified version works very fast, 1.2 sec (vs 30 sec with multicolumn index, vs 8 min with 2 separate indexes)! I accepted it as a correct answer.

Comment: Interestingly this method works slower for the date: when I changed this function to return distinct sites for the specific date, it returned result in 32 min, when simple distinct was working for 17 min. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.getsites_by_date(date) RETURNS SETOF text
    LANGUAGE sql
    AS $_$ with recursive r as (
  (select site from data_electrical as t where date = $1 order by site limit 1)
   union all
  SELECT (SELECT t.site FROM data_electrical as t WHERE date=$1 and t.site > r.site ORDER BY site LIMIT 1) from r where site is not null
)
select * from r where r.site is not null $_$;

Comment: Is there an index to support that query?  You would need one on `(date, site)`. You need very specific indexes to support this type of query.